# I was using Ubuntu and suddenly a Problem arose with the "Documents" Folder

Tags: nautilus, gnome-documents

When I Click on "Documents", I get the following message

Unable to find the requested file. Please check the spelling and try again. Unhandled error message: Error when getting information for file '/home/bbloggsbott/Documents': No such file or directory

I lost all the data in that folder. How do I rectify it?

There was the folder on the left panel. I removed it by mistake.

Comment: Restore the folder from your backup.

Comment: How did you remove the item from the left panel? what do you get if you open a terminal and type `xdg-user-dir DOCUMENTS`?

Comment: Check your `Trash` folder.